# Aspose Slide for .net C# change text color of a shape

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, aspose

I can't find a way to change text color of a rectangle autoshape, please could I have help?

here code extract:

```
// Add shape


IAutoShape shape= slide.Shapes.AddAutoShape(ShapeType.Rectangle, 20, 677, 250, 40);


                                               

((IAutoShape)shape).AddTextFrame( "Hello world!");
```

Default color is white, how can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this way and It works:

```
//In order to Have a no filled rectangle
((IAutoShape)shape).FillFormat.FillType = FillType.NoFill;


ITextFrame tf1 = ((IAutoShape)shape).TextFrame;


        // Accessing the first Paragraph of validityDate
        IParagraph para1 = tf1.Paragraphs[0];

        // Accessing the first portion
        IPortion port1 = para1.Portions[0];

        // Define new fonts
        FontData fd1 = new FontData("Arial");

        // Assign new fonts to portion
        port1.PortionFormat.LatinFont = fd1;

        // Set font color
        port1.PortionFormat.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.Solid;
        port1.PortionFormat.FillFormat.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.Gray;

        // Set the Height of the Font
        port1.PortionFormat.FontHeight = 13;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code example shows how you can change the text color of a shape using Aspose.Slides for .NET:

```cs
var paragraph = shape.TextFrame.Paragraphs[0];
paragraph.ParagraphFormat.DefaultPortionFormat.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.Solid;
paragraph.ParagraphFormat.DefaultPortionFormat.FillFormat.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.Red;
```

You will get support and answers to your questions faster if you ask questions on the [Aspose.Slides forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/slides/).

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.